# How do I modify a resource file of an external library included in my project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix/blob/master/preference-v7-simplemenu/src/main/res/layout/preference_simplemenu.xml

I have the Android preference-v7 fix library included into my Android app project and I'd like to change some things inside this xml. To be more specific, I want to align the menu and the summary textview to the right. How can I make the app use my xml file instead of the one from the library?

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.test.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7-simplemenu:+'
    compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:27.1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't pulling any new copies of the lib then you could manually replace the file in the jar once and just use that edited jar.

If you are pulling the lib during your build then you could programatically replace the file with your own file during the build process.

Perhaps show us your build process? Do you need this file to be up-to-date with a version on a repo (except for your changes)?

Comment: I don't know how or when I'm pulling it, I just followed the instructions and it said to add the following line to the gradle: compile 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7:27.1.0.0' and everything (magically) started working fine. I would be happy with just replacing the file during the build process since it seems like the simplest method, and whenever the original file gets updated on github I could just edit in the differences. There is also this line that I'm supposed to use for this menu: implementation 'com.takisoft.fix:preference-v7-simplemenu:+'

Comment: @RafaelJ please post your full gradle script

Comment: @RafaelJ I'm admittedly not familiar with gradle, what does the resulting jar look like? I'm betting you can just directly copy and edit the files that you want, then include them with something like `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.xml'], dir: 'fixed_preferences')` or something like that.

Comment: OK I got it figured out. I did something similar to what you suggested. In my case the layout id ("preference_simplemenu.xml") was declared in the styles.xml file so all I had to do was add `<style name="Preference.SimpleMenuPreference">
        <item name="android:layout">@layout/pref_simplemenu_fix</item>
    </style>` to styles.xml and my own modified simplemenu fix is located at the layout folder.